# React router navigation multipage and with react scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, react-scroll

The thing I'm trying is a multipage react app where I can navigate between pages(like from the main route '/' to '/whitepape' or 'privacyPolicy'), but I have 4 different routes('/', 'services', 'features', 'contactUs') within the main route '/' which use react-scroll to get the scrolling between those 4 components whose links are added in the Navbar(this part works as expected).

But navigating between pages like replacing entirely all 4 components with whitepaper page or privacyPolicy page, with Navbar and Footer at the same place so that I can navigate back to home.

This is what I’m stuck at any help is appreciated I’m not sure I’m following the right way to implement what I need. I have been using React Navigation in react native which is simple to understand and straightforward, wish react-router was so straight forward instead react-router is a bit confusing.

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/">
          <>
            <Hero />
            <Services />
            <Features />
            <ContactUs />
          </>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/whitepaper">
          <WhitePaper />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Navbar.js**

```
import { Link } from 'react-scroll'
import { withRouter, Link as RouterLink } from 'react-router-dom'

const menuItems = [
  {
    menuTitle: 'Home',
    pageURL: '/',
    id: 'hero'
  },
  {
    menuTitle: 'Services',
    pageURL: '/services',
    id: 'services'
  },
  {
    menuTitle: 'Features',
    pageURL: '/features',
    id: 'features'
  },
  {
    menuTitle: 'Contact Us',
    pageURL: '/contactUs',
    id: 'contactUs'
  }
]

const Navbar = ({ history }) => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null)
  const [showNav, setShowNav] = useState(false)
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl)
  const theme = useTheme()
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('sm'))
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState('/')

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsActive(history.location.pathname)
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
      if (window.scrollY > 100) {
        setShowNav(true)
      } else {
        setShowNav(false)
      }
    })
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', () => setShowNav(false))
    }
  })

  const handleMenu = event => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget)
  }

  const handleMenuClick = pageURL => {
    history.push(pageURL)
    setAnchorEl(null)
  }

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null)
  }

  const handleLinkClick = pageURL => {
    history.push(pageURL)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <AppBar
        position="static"
        elevation={0}
        className={`${classes.appBar} ${
          showNav ? classes.appBarOnScroll : classes.appBar
        }`}>
        <Container>
          <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
            <Link to="hero" smooth duration={1000}>
              <RouterLink to="/">
                <img src={logo} alt="Company Logo" className={classes.logo} />
              </RouterLink>
            </Link>
            {isMobile ? (
              <div>
                <IconButton
                  edge="start"
                  className={classes.menuButton}
                  color="inherit"
                  onClick={handleMenu}
                  aria-label="menu">
                  <MenuIcon />
                </IconButton>
                <Menu
                  className={classes.mobileMenu}
                  id="menu-appbar"
                  anchorEl={anchorEl}
                  anchorOrigin={{
                    vertical: 'top',
                    horizontal: 'right'
                  }}
                  keepMounted
                  transformOrigin={{
                    vertical: 'top',
                    horizontal: 'right'
                  }}
                  open={open}
                  onClose={handleClose}>
                  {menuItems.map(menuItem => {
                    const { menuTitle, pageURL, id } = menuItem
                    return (
                      <Link key={menuTitle} to={id} smooth duration={1000}>
                        <MenuItem
                          className={
                            isActive === pageURL
                              ? classes.mobileActiveMenuItem
                              : classes.mobileMenuItem
                          }
                          onClick={() => handleMenuClick(pageURL)}>
                          {menuTitle}
                        </MenuItem>
                      </Link>
                    )
                  })}
                </Menu>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <div className={classes.menu}>
                <Link
                  to="home"
                  smooth
                  duration={1000}
                  className={
                    isActive === '/' ? classes.menuActiveLink : classes.menuLink
                  }
                  variant="contained"
                  onClick={() => handleLinkClick('/')}>
                  Home
                </Link>
                <Link
                  to="services"
                  smooth
                  duration={1000}
                  className={
                    isActive === '/services'
                      ? classes.menuActiveLink
                      : classes.menuLink
                  }
                  variant="contained"
                  onClick={() => handleLinkClick('/services')}>
                  Services
                </Link>
                <Link
                  to="features"
                  smooth
                  duration={1000}
                  className={
                    isActive === '/features'
                      ? classes.menuActiveLink
                      : classes.menuLink
                  }
                  variant="contained"
                  onClick={() => handleLinkClick('/features')}>
                  Features
                </Link>
                <Link
                  to="contactUs"
                  smooth
                  duration={1000}
                  className={
                    isActive === '/contactUs'
                      ? classes.menuActiveLink
                      : classes.menuLink
                  }
                  variant="contained"
                  onClick={() => handleLinkClick('/contactUs')}>
                  ContactUs
                </Link>
              </div>
            )}
          </Toolbar>
        </Container>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  )
}

export default withRouter(Navbar)
```

**Footer.js**

```
import { Link } from 'react-scroll'
import { Link as RouterLink } from 'react-router-dom'

const Footer = () => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const icons = [
    {
      img: linkedin,
      alt: 'linkedin',
      url: 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/company'
    },
    {
      img: twitter,
      alt: 'twitter',
      url: 'https://twitter.com/company'
    },
    {
      img: instagram,
      alt: 'instagram',
      url: 'https://www.instagram.com/company/'
    },
    {
      img: facebook,
      alt: 'facebook',
      url: 'https://www.facebook.com/company/'
    }
  ]
  return (
    <div className={classes.footer}>
      <Container className={classes.container}>
        <Grid container spacing={4}>
          <Grid item md={3} xs={12}>
            <div className={classes.column}>
              <Link to="hero" smooth duration={1000}>
                <RouterLink to="/">
                  <img className={classes.logo} src={logo} alt="Company Logo" />
                </RouterLink>
              </Link>
            </div>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item md={3} xs={12}>
            <div className={classes.column}>
              <div>
                <Grid item>
                  <span className={classes.linksTitle}>USEFUL LINKS</span>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item className={classes.links}>
                  <RouterLink to="/whitepaper" replace className={classes.link}>
                    <span className={classes.span}>White Paper</span>
                  </RouterLink>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item className={classes.links}>
                  <a
                    href="mailto:xyz@comapmy.com"
                    className={classes.link}>
                    <span className={classes.span}>Email Our CEO</span>
                  </a>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item className={classes.links}>
                  <RouterLink to="/" className={classes.link}>
                    <span className={classes.span}>Privacy Policy</span>
                  </RouterLink>
                </Grid>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item md={3} xs={12}>
            <div className={classes.column}>
              {icons.map(icon => {
                return (
                  <a href={icon.url} key={icon.alt}>
                    <img
                      className={classes.icon}
                      src={icon.img}
                      alt={icon.alt}
                    />
                  </a>
                )
              })}
            </div>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item md={3} xs={12}>
            <div className={classes.top}>
              <Link to="hero" smooth duration={1000}>
                <RouterLink to="/">
                  <div>
                    <img src={top} alt="back to top" />
                    <p>Back To Top</p>
                  </div>
                </RouterLink>
              </Link>
            </div>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid container>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <div className={classes.footerBottom}>
              <p className={classes.copyright}>
                © 2021 Copyrights •{' '}
                <Link to="hero" smooth duration={1000}>
                  <RouterLink to="/" className={classes.company}>
                    <span>company.com</span>
                  </RouterLink>
                </Link>
              </p>
            </div>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Footer
```

Comment: Interesting. I find react-router to be much more straight forward than react-navigation in RN, /shrug. What exactly is the issue here? Is it that your `path="/whitepaper"` isn't reachable/rendering? Are you rendering a `Router` around/above `App` in the ReactTree so there's a routing context? (*I suspect there is since you aren't complaining about errors related to that*)

Comment: @DrewReese I have 4 components(Hero, Services, Features, and ContactUs) all these are rendered in sequence, whose links are in the Navbar I wanted a scrolling when these links in the navbar are clicked to scroll to that component which I was able to achieve with react-scroll `Link` which works as expected but now I want to replace all these 4 components with a new page i.e. either Whitepaper or PrivacyPolicy page whose link are added in the Footer. I have used Link from `react-router-dom` as RouterLink iIsee the change in URL but the whitepaper page is not rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the `Switch` component path order and specificity matter. This isn't a detail that is overtly called out in their docs though. You want to order your more specific paths *before* less specific paths. Think of `path` as more of a prefix, and you'll see that "/" is a path prefix for ***all*** paths.

The `Switch` returns and renders the first matching path it finds in its children.

Just invert the order of your paths such that `"/whitepaper"` is listed prior to the more general/less specific `"/"` path.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/whitepaper">
          <WhitePaper />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/">
          <>
            <Hero />
            <Services />
            <Features />
            <ContactUs />
          </>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Now that I can navigate from whitepaper page back to hero/services/features/contactUs using Navbar but when I click on either of those links in Navbar It takes me to the hero instead of that specific component say like contactUs component from whitepaper.

Comment: And also i get this warning `Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>` maybe that's because I have nested Link from `react-router-dom` in Link from `react-scroll`. Any idea how I can resolve it? And is the most efficient way I can achieve it or are there any good practices for that?

Comment: @saicharanpogul `react-router-dom` out-of-the-box really only handles navigating to pages, but *not* to a specific part of a page, but luckily there is [react-router-hash-link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link) where you can link to anchor tags within a page. About the `<a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>` issue... yeah, you can't nest them. I suspect the `react-router-dom` `Link` components aren't doing much for you since you aren't technically rendering your hero components on individual routes. You can probably remove the `react-router-dom` links.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense I removed `react-router-dom` `Link`.  Not sure using `react-router-hash-link` `HashLink` and 'react-scroll` `Link` will turn out as nesting causes warnings.

Comment: @SaicharanPogul I've not ever heard of `react-scroll` (*well, maybe I have and just never looked into it*), but I would think internal to the hero component you could continue using the scrolling links that you say work, and external you can link to specific anchor/hashlinks on the page and they *should* be scrolled to. This being said, I have no idea if these two libraries have any conflicting behaviors. Does the internal/external part make sense though?

Comment: Internal/External is it the parent and child element you are referring to? Yeah, I need to check it. But for now I'm satisfied with what i have now. Maybe i will work on more details, once I'm done with everything else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232627/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-saicharan-pogul).